# Why I can't get entry value from tkinter as a file name....I'm trying to save image with a given name

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to capture an image with the user-given name but I can't get the value from the Tkinter entry.
Here's my code. But It says the 'Application' object has no attribute 'txt'.

```
class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, output_path = "./"):
        self.vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # capture video frames, 0 is your default video camera
        self.output_path = output_path  # store output path
        self.current_image = None  # current image from the camera

        self.root = tk.Tk()  # initialize root window
        self.root.title("Window")  # set window title
        # self.destructor function gets fired when the window is closed
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.destructor)

        self.panel = tk.Label(self.root)  # initialize image panel
        self.panel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        # create a button, that when pressed, will take the current frame and save it to file
        lbl=tk.Label(self.root,text="Insert Image Name", font=("Arial Bold",10))
        lbl.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        
        txt = tk.Entry(self.root,width=10)
        txt.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        
        btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="Capture", command=self.take_snapshot)
        btn.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        
        self.video_loop()


    def take_snapshot(self):
        """ Take snapshot and save it to the file """
        index=self.txt.get()
        filename =index+".jpg"
        p = os.path.join(self.output_path, filename)  # construct output path
        self.current_image.save(p, "png")  # save image as jpeg file
        print("[INFO] saved {}".format(filename))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the `tk.Entry`

```py
txt = tk.Entry(self.root,width=10)
txt.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
```

You don't save the variable to `self` so you can't access it using `self.txt`. To fix that just change those 2 lines to:

```py
self.txt = tk.Entry(self.root,width=10)
self.txt.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
```